# how to define a field that will enable me to search alphabetically

Tags: solr, lucene, schema, custom-field-type

In SOLR, I would like to define a field which will fetch results alphabetically. So, If I search for 'S' it will bring me **only** results that starts with S (I search on one field).
This is how I tried to define it, but, it brings me also results which do not start with 'S'

```
<fieldType name="text_general_edge_ngram" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
       <analyzer type="index">
         <tokenizer class="solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory"/>
         <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="5" side="front"/>
       </analyzer>
       <analyzer type="query">
          <tokenizer class="solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory"/>
       </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

The query I use:

```
http://MySERVER/solr/content/select/?q=alpha_title:s&start=0&rows=15
```

Seems to me it is I should have used a ngrams tokenizer and not filter. Will test and update.

Comment: Can you share the query you're using?

Comment: Couldn't you just go with a normal field, and then send the query like this: `http://MySERVER/solr/content/select/?q=alpha_title:s*&start=0&rows=15` with the star saying that it must start with s.

Comment: @Andreas Stokholm - I will try this (new to me) but, isn't it a bit slower than tokenizing it right in the first place?

Comment: I second the suggestion by Andreas.  It could be slower at query time, but will be query at index time.

Answer (score 0):

As I thought, I need to use the ngram tokenizer in the analyzer instead of the ngram filter.
So, this is the working schema:

```
<fieldType name="text_general_edge_ngram" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="org.apache.solr.analysis.EdgeNGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="5"/> 
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Answer (score 0):

Itay Moav asked me to put my comment as an answer, so here goes:

You should go for an alias search, like this:

`http://MySERVER/solr/content/select/?q=alpha_title:s*&start=0&rows=15`

With the star saying that it must start with s.